# Mysql problem to see if two selects are the same

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT table_grouping_code, gui_field_code, gui_interface_id, dictionary_code, property_name, position INTO @test
FROM table_grouping_layout
WHERE company_code = "TEST";

SELECT table_grouping_code, gui_field_code, gui_interface_id, dictionary_code, property_name, position INTO @doximtrx
FROM table_grouping_layout
WHERE company_code = "DOXIMTRX";

select @test = @doximtrx;
```

I tried this, that seems very logica to me, but mysql says: ERROR CODE 1222: the used select statement have a different number of columns. How can it be possible?? I copied the query, only changing the code.

[Example of data in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22R0K.png)

Comment: Do you want to assert a boolean value if both result sets are identical?  Something else?

Comment: Yes I just want a true or false

Comment: On a side note: Be careful with your delimiters. Double quotes are usually delimiters for names, while it is single quotes that delimit string literals. Mixing these can lead to unexpected results. See this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab139798d912a3237e0daf586bc889d9

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select many columns into a single variable. The correct syntax for that part of your query is:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(table_grouping_code ORDER BY table_grouping_code)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(gui_field_code ORDER BY gui_field_code)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(gui_interface_id ORDER BY gui_interface_id)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(dictionary_code ORDER BY dictionary_code)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(property_name ORDER BY property_name)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(position ORDER BY position)
FROM
    table_grouping_layout
WHERE
    company_code = 'TEST'
INTO
    @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4, @t5, @t6;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(table_grouping_code ORDER BY table_grouping_code)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(gui_field_code ORDER BY gui_field_code)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(gui_interface_id ORDER BY gui_interface_id)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(dictionary_code ORDER BY dictionary_code)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(property_name ORDER BY property_name)
,   GROUP_CONCAT(position ORDER BY position)
FROM
    table_grouping_layout
WHERE
    company_code = 'DOXIMTRX'
INTO
    @d1, @d2, @d3, @d4, @d5, @d6;
```

How to compare results is a different story:

```
SELECT ifNull(
      @t1 = @d1
  and @t2 = @d2
  and @t3 = @d3
  and @t4 = @d4
  and @t5 = @d5
  and @t6 = @d6
, false
) as result;
```

**TEST DATA:**

```
select * from table_grouping_layout;
```

| table_grouping_code | gui_field_code | gui_interface_id | dictionary_code | property_name | position | company_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | DOXIMTRX |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | TEST |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | DOXIMTRX |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | TEST |

**QUERY RESULT:**

| result |
| --- |
| 0 |

Comment: ERROR CODE: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row. That's not the solution to my problem

Comment: It means that the company_code is not unique. In that case you can make it working by adding LIMIT 1 at the end of SELECT part. It would be good to suplement the question with the example data stored in the database.

Comment: You are right there are multiple lines with that code. But if I add a limit 1 I don't check all I want

Comment: Yes. That's true.. I was assuming that the company_code is unique. In that case you can try to aggregate companies into single row and again... an example dataset added to your question would be really helpful :)

Comment: I've amended my query in the answer to make it working for non unique company_code corresponding to the example data you have supplemented to your question.

Comment: Beautiful, ty. But I think mysql should have an operator/function which checks if two queries gives same results.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are meant to hold one value. Neither one row nor one column nor one table.

Comparing two data sets can be achieved with a combination of `UNION`and `EXCEPT` or with a full outer join. Unfortunately, MySQL does neither support `EXCEPT` nor `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Here is a workaround:

```
with t as (select * from table_grouping_layout where company_code = 'TEST')
   , d as (select * from table_grouping_layout where company_code = 'DOXIMTRX')
select 'MISMATCH' as status, t.position
from table_grouping_layout t
join table_grouping_layout d 
  on t.position = d.position
  and not 
  (
    t.table_grouping_code <=> t.table_grouping_code  and
    t.gui_field_code      <=> t.gui_field_code       and
    t.gui_interface_id    <=> t.gui_interface_id     and
    t.dictionary_code     <=> t.dictionary_code      and
    t.property_name       <=> t.property_name
  )
union all
select 'TEST MISSING' as status, position
from d
where position not in (select position from t)
union all
select 'DOXIMTRX MISSING' as status, position
from t
where position not in (select position from d)
order by position;
```

Another approach using aggregation:

```
select
  position,
  case 
    when sum(company_code = 'TEST') = 0 then 'TEST MISSING'
    when sum(company_code = 'DOXIMTRX') = 0 then 'DOXIMTRX MISSING'
    when not
    (
      max(table_grouping_code) <=> min(table_grouping_code) and count(table_grouping_code) in (0,2)
      max(gui_field_code)      <=> min(gui_field_code)      and count(gui_field_code)      in (0,2)
      max(gui_interface_id)    <=> min(gui_interface_id)    and count(gui_interface_id)    in (0,2)
      max(dictionary_code)     <=> min(dictionary_code)     and count(dictionary_code)     in (0,2)
      max(property_name)       <=> min(property_name)       and count(property_name)       in (0,2)
    ) then 'MISMATCH'
    else 'MATCH' end as status
from table_grouping_layout
where company_code in ('TEST', 'DOXIMTRX')
group by position
order by position;
```